# rows().every() is selecting all rows(error) dataTables jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I just want the numberOfSelectedRows to be only showing the rows that I selected.
For example if I selected 2 rows I just want this variable to be 2. But for me it comes out to all the rows. 
Same for when I use the api.rows().every() function. In the [docs for rows().every()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) it says that only selected rows are looped but for me it loops through all the rows in the table. What am I doing wrong?

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        select: true,
        buttons: [{
          extend: 'copyHtml5',
          text: 'Copy Selected Rows',
          header: false,
          customize: function(data, config, api){

            var numberOfSelectedRows = api.rows().data().length;
            console.log(numberOfSelectedRows);
          }
      }]
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  <body>

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Position</th>
             <th>Office</th>
             <th>Age</th>
             <th>Start date</th>
             <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
             <td>System Architect</td>
             <td>Edinburgh</td>
             <td>61</td>
             <td>2011/04/25</td>
             <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Garrett Winters</td>
             <td>Accountant</td>
             <td>Tokyo</td>
             <td>63</td>
             <td>2011/07/25</td>
             <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Ashton Cox</td>
             <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
             <td>San Francisco</td>
             <td>66</td>
             <td>2009/01/12</td>
             <td>$86,000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be changed from:

```
var numberOfSelectedRows = api.rows().data().length
```

to this:

```
var numberOfSelectedRows = api.rows('.selected').data().length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count function to get a selected count of rows.

Count how many rows there are with the class selected:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
alert( 'Rows '+table.rows( '.selected' ).count()+' are selected' );
```

Count the number of data entries (i.e. rows) in a table:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
if ( ! table.data().count() ) {
    alert( 'Empty table' );
}
```

You can see the document [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/count())